# What is the cardinality of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e the set of all 2 by 2 real matrices( $|M_2(\mathbb{R})|$)?

Comment: you are saying that the entries are real so obviously the domain is $\mathbb{R}$. do u mean to  ask anything else?

Comment: The set $\mathcal M_2(\mathbb{R})$ isn't a function or a relation, so it's not clear what you mean with domain.

Comment: I think that you ask for the dimension of $M_2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: oops!what is the cardinality?

Comment: you can identify ${M_2}(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and hence it is uncountable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cardinality of $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R^4$ which is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n$, including $n=1$.